# Can I declare and fill an array from an XML document without looping?

Tags: c#, xml

I 'd like to fill a new string array with elements from an XML document.

In VBA I've managed this logic with a collection:

```
For Each x In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//a")
    MyCollection.add (x.Attributes.getNamedItem("href").Text)
Next x
```

But what I really want to do is get the same collection in to an array in C#, something like:

```
string[] MyArray = new string[]
    {
        xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//a").Attributes.getNamedItem("href").Text
    };
```

Is this possible? Or some similar way to do it without looping and adding individually to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do

```
string[] MyArray = XDocument.Parse(xml).XPathSelectElements("//a").Select(e => e.Attributes("href").FirstOrDefault().Value).ToArray()`
```

Edit: Requires `Using System.Xml.XPath` and `Using System.XML.Linq` to work

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it gives me an error: 'XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'XPathSelectElements' and no extension method 'XPathSelectElements' accepting a first argument of type 'XDocument' could be found

Comment: The `XPathSelectElements` method is an extension method, defined in a class in the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace. (So you need to add `using System.Xml.XPath;` to your usings to be able to use that extension method)

Comment: Thanks RajN this worked perfectly after that little help from bassfader

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to achieve something like that:

```
string[] MyArray = xmlDoc
    .SelectNodes("//a")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(e => e.Attributes.GetNamedItem("href").InnerText)
    .ToArray();
```

Don't forget to import Linq (`using System.Linq;`)

Comment: Thanks, but what class is 'doc' - I was using MSXML2.DOMDocument60 and this code gives me several compile errors - I tried XDocument and that didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been your "xmlDoc" variable. I've updated the answer

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I did try that, was still incorrect but then I realised it was the Capital "S" on SelectNodes - I now have it compiling and am just about to test it.

Comment: I got an error on this one, "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Xml.XmlNode'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface." -  I will try different XmlNode types, maybe one from MSXML2

Comment: `.Cast<MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode>()` doesn't work either , the `e.Attributes` becomes invalid

Comment: Oh, you use the COM object, and not the .NET one. This will work on the `XmlDocument` type from `System.Xml`, but I don't know about the COM's MSXML2.DOMDocument. Even so, I would suggest you to read up on the [LINQ To XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-linq-to-xml), as this is the preferred way to handle XML documents in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have an accepted answer already but I upvoted this one too - I am totally new to LINQ to be honest, it seems amazing but I have not yet practiced enough to know what it's doing.